# Регулярное выражение для пароля

Tags: регулярные-выражения

уже продолжительное время сижу над такой регуляркой, нужно проверить строку, чтобы она содержала как минимум 3 заглавных буквы и как минимум 3 цифры, срока не должна содержать спец. символы, т.е в строке могут быть только заглавные буквы, цифры и буквы нижнего регистра. Может быть у кого-то есть идеи как такую регулярку написать?)

- aaaaaSaaSasAd212D - валидна
- gfg1fdgdSSSdsad3f3 - валидна
- dfsdfsfdf3fsdfsfF - не валидна

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Переношу из комментария в ответ:

Шаблон составил следующим образом:
`(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z].*[A-Z])[A-Za-z0-9]{8,30}`

`[A-Za-z0-9]{8,30}` - выбираем любую последовательность букв и цифр начиная от 8 и заканчивая 30 символами
`(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z].*[A-Z])` - проверяем наличие 3 заглавных букв
`(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9])` - проверяем наличие 3 цифр.

В последних двух условиях дополнительно прописываем `.*`, так как заглавные буквы, либо цифры могут быть размазаны по строке.

Важно что бы не было включено игнорирование регистра в методе используемом данным регулярным выражением.

Пример: https://regex101.com/r/oYaAle/1